# Which particular 10-year note does the daily 10-year treasury note yield refer to?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds, treasury

Question might be a bit obscure. The yield of the 10-year treasury note is reported daily on TV and in the papers. Since there are notes with different maturities in circulation, also more importantly, different coupons, which particular 10-year note does the daily yield refer to? The notes auctioned on Jan 1, 2018, Jan 1, 2017, February 35, 2010?

Comment: `February 35, 2010` Assuming this is a typo. Are you sure about what you heard ? Generally when they say/show yield they always mention the bond they are referring to as it would be pointless without the tenor. It might be you have started watching the show/chart in the middle. Or you can refer to the figures here to find out https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield

Comment: @DumbCoder That was obviously (to me) not a typo. It was a joke.

Comment: @DumbCoder To be precise, I'm referring to the numbers on the front page of the WSJ, right next to the S&P 500, Stoxx, etc. "February 35" was a joke out of frustration about the vagueness of this number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the source, but if they're just referring to the yield, I think it's usually the most recently auctioned bond (this is what Bloomberg quotes if you don't override anything, and Bloomberg is likely the source that the TV stations at least are getting it from). Right now (June 22, 2018), that's the one which matures May 15 2028 and has a coupon of 2.875.